# KSH measure elapsed time

Tags: unix, ksh, hp-ux

I am trying to find the day difference from the last time a password was rest to the current. So i have this so far. I am trying to just convert that date to days so i can subtract the current date in days - the last reset date in days and get a integer value.

```
$ LASTRESETDATE=$(echo $(passwd -s) | cut -d' ' -f3)
$ echo $LASTRESETDATE
12/15/16
```

Looking the the date verion i have there is no option for -d

```
$ date -h
date: illegal option -- h
Usage: date [-u] [+format]
       date [-u] [mmddhhmm[[cc]yy]]
       date [-a [-]sss.fff]
```

Comment: **edit**  : given you're stuck with hp-ux (and you're probably in a corporate environment where you **can't** install GNU tools), you'll have to code your own functions to convert dates to manipuable values. My answer at stackoverflow.com/questions/8606520/converting-dates-in-shel‌​l/… is part of the solution. Search for `[linux] awk date math` (and other similar search targets) to find more complete solutions. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

When I was unfortunate enough to have to slog through HP-UX idiosyncrasies, I'd often write my own little programs to do exactly what I wanted. Provided your hokey-pux machine is POSIXy, then you could do:

```
$ cat fromnow.c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct tm parsed;
    strptime(argv[1], argv[2], &parsed);
    printf("%.0f\n", difftime(time(NULL), mktime(&parsed)));
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it:

```
$ cc -o fromnow fromnow.c
```

Run it:

```
$ ./fromnow 5/13/13 %D
119451988
```

which will then calculate the *number of seconds* between the current time and the date "5/13/13" formatted in American style "%D". The first argument is the date, the second argument is the format specifier for parsing that date. See [man strptime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html) for options.

This could be made more general, or less, depending upon how much you need to do date calculations.

Comment: No one on my team knows C so I can't use it. I have the options to use Perl or KSH

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of `ksh` you're using.

```
[STEP 101] $ echo ${.sh.version}
Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01
[STEP 102] $ date=12/15/16
[STEP 103] $ [[ $date =~ (..)/(..)/(..) ]]
[STEP 104] $ date=20${.sh.match[3]}-${.sh.match[1]}-${.sh.match[2]}
[STEP 105] $ echo $date
2016-12-15
[STEP 106] $ old_seconds=$( printf '%(%s)T' $date )
[STEP 107] $ echo $old_seconds
1481797007
[STEP 108] $ now_seconds=$( printf '%(%s)T' )
[STEP 109] $ echo $now_seconds
1487845024
[STEP 110] $ (( diff = now_seconds - old_seconds ))
[STEP 111] $ echo $diff
6048017
[STEP 112] $ echo $(( diff / 86400 )) days
70 days
[STEP 113] $
```

Comment: $ echo ${.sh.version}
ksh: ${.sh.version}: bad substitution

Comment: So you're using a very old ksh (maybe ksh88?).

Comment: Yep found this $ strings /bin/ksh | grep Version | tail -2
@(#)Version 11/16/88

Comment: @user3753693 My condolences.

Comment: @bishop my life would be so much easier if i could at least use python

Answer (score 1):

When you have `awk`, you can calculate the difference with

```
LASTRESETDATE="12/15/16"
endd="$(date '+%m/%d/%y')"

awk -v startdate="${LASTRESETDATE}" -v enddate="${endd}" 'BEGIN {
   split(startdate,A,"[/]");
   T1=mktime(A[3] " " A[1] " " A[2] " 12 0 0");
   split(enddate,B,"[/]");
   T2=mktime(B[3] " " B[1] " " B[2] " 12 0 0");
   diffdays=(T2-T1)/(3600*24)
   printf("%s\n",diffdays);
}'
```

When you need this often, and you do not have (the right version of) awk, you can make a lookup-table on another system.
With `awk`:

```
startd="12/15/16"
endd="$(date '+%m/%d/%y')"

awk -v startdate="${startd}" -v enddate="${endd}" 'BEGIN {
   split(startdate,A,"[/]");
   T1=mktime(A[3] " " A[1] " " A[2] " 12 0 0");
   split(enddate,B,"[/]");
   T2=mktime(B[3] " " B[1] " " B[2] " 12 0 0");
   linenr=1;
   while (T1 < T2) {
      printf("%d %s\n",linenr++, strftime("%m/%d/%y",T1));
      T1+=3600*24;
   }
}'
```

Of course you can make a list with Excel or another tool.

EDIT: removed var that I only used prototyping the solution.

Comment: When I use this it says "ksh: str: parameter not set" when i remove the -v string=$"{str}". It gives an error on the mktime function saying it is not defined.

Comment: I removed the unused string. The mktime is a gawk extension, your awk version is not supporting it. When you can't get gawk, consider making a lookup.csv file from excel witjh one date on each line. With something like `grep -n` (or a second excel column) you can get linenumbers and look up the difference.